# package.json and Eslint glob extension

Tags: javascript, eslint, glob, package.json

My package.json is below. How do I update it so that eslint runs on:

**src** and **test** directories

for

**.js** and **.jsx** files only? Right now the * wild card is including .json which I don't want.

**package.json**

```js
{
...

"lint": "eslint {src/**/*.js*,test/**/*.js*}

...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to trade brevity for specificity here:

```
{
...

"lint": "eslint {src/**/*.js,src/**/*.jsx,test/**/*.js,test/**/*.jsx}"

...
}
```

Comment: Marked this as the answer for now, would be nice if there was a more concise method. But this does work

Answer (score 9):

You can read in [eslint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface):

> Please note that when passing a glob as a parameter, it will be expanded by your shell. The results of the expansion can vary depending on your shell, and its configuration. If you want to use node glob syntax, you have to quote your parameter (using double quotes if you need it to run in Windows), as follows:

So it would be advisable to use double quotes. Once you use double quotes (which need to be escaped inside json string) you can slightly modify your pattern e.g.

```
{
...

"lint": "eslint \"{src,test}/**/*.{js,jsx}\""

...
}
```

Test using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=%2F%7Bsrc%2Ctest%7D%2F**%2F*.%7Bjs%2Cjsx%7D&f=%2Fpackage.json%2C%2Ftest%2Fstaging.js%2C%2Ftest%2Fproduction.js%2C%2Fsrc%2Fpackage.json%2C%2Fsrc%2Fservices%2Ftimezone.jsx%2C%2Fsrc%2Fcontrollers%2Fhealth.js%2C%2Fsrc%2Fcontrollers%2Fuser.module.ts%2C%2Fassets%2Flogo.png%2C%2Fassets%2Flogo_small.png%2C%2Fassets%2Ffavicon.ico) (globster.xyz require `/` at the beginning but eslint doesn't, not sure why...)

There is usually more than one way to achieve what you want but I think this would be the most concise.

Comment: I approve this solution for windows machines.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to run eslint on one directory:

```
"lint": "node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext js --ext jsx src"
```

I think you can just add the `test` directory onto the end after `src` to do both. There is more information [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface)

Comment: What about if I have 2 folders, src and test

Comment: I think you can just add the `test` directory onto the end after `src` to do both. There is more information [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface)